# Checking for Duplicates, using mysqli_num_row Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building an Inventory page for a project and I am trying to check, when I attempt to insert a new item if its already in the database. I am running into a problem with the mysqli_num_rows function in such a way that it asks for a parameter. I'm pretty sure my query beforehand is working so I dont understand why its doing this. Is it because the query returns 0 rows? Below is the code.

Also I am using an include for the mysqli_connect so its not in the code below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["product_name"])){
$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["product_name"]);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["price"]);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["category"]);
$subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["subcategory"]);
$details = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["details"]);

$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name = '$product_name'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "sorry you tried to add a duplicate <a href = Inventory_list.php> Click here </a>";
exit();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO products       (product_name,price,details,category,subcategory,date_added)
VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category',
'$subcategory',now())") or die("Update Error: ".mysqli_error());
$pid = mysqli_insert_id();
$newname = $pid.jpg;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"../Images/$newname");
}

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? And you said `asks for a parameter`. mysql_num_row has a parameter

Comment: I have fixed the stupid issue by changing mysql_num_rows to mysqli_num_rows.Stupid bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "sorry you tried to add a duplicate <a href = Inventory_list.php> Click here </a>";
exit();
}
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "sorry you tried to add a duplicate <a href = Inventory_list.php> Click here </a>";
exit();
}
```